# Issue with selecting an input checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am really new to JavaScript and jQuery. I have a checkbox and I want to verify if it is checked or not. So, I am checking the click event on input tag.

This is how the code looks like:

```js
$('#ss_options_checkbox').click(function() {
  alert("check box clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-sm-8'>
  <div class="radio-block">
    <input type="checkbox" id="ss_options_checkbox" class="ss-options-checkbox ss-hidden-checkbox-input">
    <label for="ss_options_checkbox" class="ss-checkbox-legend">All SS</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to see on click whether the checkbox is checked or not, but I tried the above very simple code which creates alert box on clicking the checkbox.

But when I select/unselect the checkbox, nothing is happening. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you want the "change" event instead of the "click" event

Comment: Are you clicking the checkbox or the label?

Comment: @HereticMonkey: I didn't understand your question. I select/ unselect the textbox.

Comment: There is no textbox. The checkbox is the square form element, the label is the text. In any case, I moved your code to a Stack Snippet to show that it's actually working as intended already.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey. I see it is working in the stck snippet. Somehow it is not working in my code. No idea why that is happening

Comment: Hey, I appreciate you trying to post the minimal amount of code, believe me! Looks like it might be a bit too minimal though. I'd start adding stuff from your real code until it breaks. Maybe Bootstrap? Sometimes that interferes by rewriting the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to make it prettier.

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey. I will have to figure out what is failing before posting the big code. Just about this, there is <a> tag and it is working perfectly fine:

```
$("#advanced-ss-options-link").click(function(){
                console.log("yayay");
```
I will find what is failing and then post the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if checkbox is checked with jQuery by using **.is(':checked')** on the input element:

```js
$('#ss_options_checkbox').change(function() {
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="radio-block">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ss_options_checkbox" class="ss-options-checkbox ss-hidden-checkbox-input">
        <label for="ss_options_checkbox" class="ss-checkbox-legend">All SS</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just `alert(this.checked);` if you wanted to use less code :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey you're totally right! But the author probably wants jQuery solution as I see :)